# Coupled degeneracies vs uncoupled degeneracies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, perturbation-theory

I am reading about degenerate perturbation theory. I am specifically concerned with this problem $\frac{-h^2}{2I} \frac{d^2}{d\phi^2} \psi = E \psi$.

Here, we get eigenstates of the form $ e^{\pm ni\phi}$. Now, an electric field is applied, giving the perturbation of $p E cos(\phi)$. Now, it is said to directly use the states $sin (n\phi)$ and $cos (n\phi)$.

How do we know to do this? This is done and then normal degenerate perturbation theory is used.

I understand that in general we can use the first order perturbation to break the degeneracy and this becomes the right basis to use. But in this case, $sin (n\phi)$ and $cos (n\phi)$ don't do this. So, how do we know these are the right states to use for the second order degenerate perturbation theory?

Comment: Consider parity…

Comment: why does parity matter?

Comment: because the SE is unchanged under $\phi\mapsto -\phi$…

Comment: i am really confused by what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the solutions of the SE in a potential with $V(\phi)=V(-\phi)$ can be chosen to have good parity.  This is because if $\psi(\phi)$ is a solution, so is $\psi(-\phi)$, and thus so are $\psi(\phi)\pm \psi(-\phi)$.  Thus, for instance, with the harmonic oscillator $V(x)\sim x^2$ the solutions $\psi_n(x)$ are either even or odd (depending on $n$).

Here we have a similar situation, with $V(\phi)=V(-\phi)=0$.  Thus, you can choose $e^{in\phi}\pm e^{-in\phi}$ which are, up to normalization, just $\cos(n\phi)$ and $\sin(n\phi)$.

Since your perturbation is symmetric under $\phi$, the perturbation will connect states with the same parity, i.e. it will connect $\sin(n\phi)$ to $\sin((n\pm 1)\phi)$ and the same for $\cos(n\phi)$ and $\cos((n\pm 1)\phi)$.  However, it cannot connect $\sin(n\phi)$ to $\cos(n\phi)$, so your perturbation will be diagonal in the degenerate subspaces if you choose those basis states.

This justifies the choice of the trigonometric function as better adapted than the exponential to your perturbative approach.

Comment: Thank you, that made sense